# Подскажите, почему не происходит вызов самодельного метода?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Создал простетский метод, записал его в прототип массивов, появился вопрос по поподву вызова этого метода:

```js
Array.prototype.monkey=function(){
  for(var k=0;k<this.length;k++){
    document.write(this[k].toUpperCase())
  }
}

var some = ["a", "b", "c"]; // (1) 
some.monkey() // (1) результат: A , B , C


//["a", "b", "c"].monkey();  //(2) результат "Uncaught, TypeError..."
```

В варианте под цифрой (1) всё прекрасно работает, и вроде бы логично выглядит, вариант же (2) не срабатывает, выбрасывая `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'monkey' of undefined"`. У меня единственное предположение, что `this` не на что указывать в этом методе? Или я не прав? Просьба, объясните пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Механизм автоматической подстановки точек с запятой в JS - очень коварная штука. Когда вы писали что-то типа

```
doSmtn()
["a"]
```

То вы как бы говорили обратиться к элементу `a` результата вызова функции `doSmtn`, что, разумеется, полнейший бред. Но стоит только добавить точку с запятой, как все сразу начинает работать так, как Вы это имели в виду.

```js
Array.prototype.monkey=function(){
  for(var k=0;k<this.length;k++){
    document.write(this[k].toUpperCase())
  }
}

var some = ["a", "b", "c"]; // (1) 
some.monkey(); // <- точка с запятой :)


["a", "b", "c"].monkey(); // и никаких ошибок
```

Comment: smellyshovel, Вы серьездно? Я в шоке! Спасибо, лайк, не знал. . .

Comment: smellyshovel, прикол ещё в том, что мне по какой-то неведомой причине самому мозолила глаза эта строка [...].monkey(); как будто это  мать его кит выброшенный на берег...=/

Comment: @Muranx на StackOverflow исчерпывающее решение принято помечать галочкой (слева от ответа). И да, самый главный вывод из моего ответа - **всегда** ставьте точку с запятой **вручную** там, где ее можно (и нужно) поставить.

Comment: smellyshovel, удачи тебе !